# Hidden value is not setting of a select tag in struts UI tag

Tags: jquery, html, struts2

I've a select option for which I want to set the selected value in a hidden input tag. I've defined these in FTL files. I'm using struts tags to store. But, still its not storing. Here is my code

```
<select id="eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimBonusInBPS" name="form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS"
                                                class="bb-search-action-dropdown selectpicker ">
   <option value="">--Select--</option>
   <option value="0" <@s.property value="%{form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS == 0 ? 'selected':''}"/>>1 year(0%)</option>
   <option value="20" <@s.property value="%{form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS == 20 ? 'selected':''}"/>>2 years(20%)</option>

</select>
<input type="hidden" id="ncb" name="ncb" value="<@s.property value='%{form.details.insurancePolicyToTransfer.noClaimBonusInBPS}'/>" />
```

Whenever I click on that select option, it should save the value. But, its not saving. Anything wrong in the code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of doing this? You're already submitting the form, so you'll have the value both on the client and server side. Why have a hidden field with duplicate information?

Answer (score 0):

Add `change` event handler to `select` tag.

When you click on option the value is saved in `select` element automatically.

Take the value from that element and copy it into the hidden field.

Roughly, assuming you're loading the JS properly:

```javascript
$(function() {
  $("#eForm_form_details_insurancePolicyToTransfer_noClaimBonusInBPS")
    .change(function() {
      $("#ncb").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This is done through JS which I don't want. I want it by struts UI tag. Anyways, thank you.